# Meaning of the benchmark variables in snakemake

Tags: psutil, snakemake

I included a `benchmark` directive to some of the rules in my snakemake workflow, and the resulting files have the following header:

```
s   h:m:s   max_rss max_vms max_uss max_pss io_in   io_out  mean_load
```

[The only documentation I've found](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#benchmark-rules) mentions a "benchmark txt file (which will contain a tab-separated table of run times and memory usage in MiB)".

I can guess that columns 1 and 2 are two different ways of displaying the time taken to execute the rule (in seconds, and converted to hours, minutes and seconds).

`io_in` and `io_out` likely related to disk read and write activity, but in what units are they measured?

What are the others? Is this documented somewhere?

#### Edit: Looking at the source code

I've found the following piece of code in [`/snakemake/benchmark.py`](https://pypkg.com/pypi/snakemake/f/snakemake/benchmark.py), that might well be where the benchmark data come from:

```python
def _update_record(self):
    """Perform the actual measurement"""
    # Memory measurements
    rss, vms, uss, pss = 0, 0, 0, 0
    # I/O measurements
    io_in, io_out = 0, 0
    # CPU seconds
    cpu_seconds = 0
    # Iterate over process and all children
    try:
        main = psutil.Process(self.pid)
        this_time = time.time()
        for proc in chain((main,), main.children(recursive=True)):
            meminfo = proc.memory_full_info()
            rss += meminfo.rss
            vms += meminfo.vms
            uss += meminfo.uss
            pss += meminfo.pss
            ioinfo = proc.io_counters()
            io_in += ioinfo.read_bytes
            io_out += ioinfo.write_bytes
            if self.bench_record.prev_time:
                cpu_seconds += proc.cpu_percent() / 100 * (
                    this_time - self.bench_record.prev_time)
        self.bench_record.prev_time = this_time
        if not self.bench_record.first_time:
            self.bench_record.prev_time = this_time
        rss /= 1024 * 1024
        vms /= 1024 * 1024
        uss /= 1024 * 1024
        pss /= 1024 * 1024
        io_in /= 1024 * 1024
        io_out /= 1024 * 1024
    except psutil.Error as e:
        return
    # Update benchmark record's RSS and VMS
    self.bench_record.max_rss = max(self.bench_record.max_rss or 0, rss)
    self.bench_record.max_vms = max(self.bench_record.max_vms or 0, vms)
    self.bench_record.max_uss = max(self.bench_record.max_uss or 0, uss)
    self.bench_record.max_pss = max(self.bench_record.max_pss or 0, pss)
    self.bench_record.io_in = io_in
    self.bench_record.io_out = io_out
    self.bench_record.cpu_seconds += cpu_seconds
```

So this seems to come from functionalities provided by [`psutil`](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Benchmarking in snakemake could certainly be better documented, but psutil is documanted [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/psutil/wikis/Documentation.wiki):

```
get_memory_info()
Return a tuple representing RSS (Resident Set Size) and VMS (Virtual Memory Size) in bytes.
On UNIX RSS and VMS are the same values shown by ps. 
On Windows RSS and VMS refer to "Mem Usage" and "VM Size" columns of taskmgr.exe.

psutil.disk_io_counters(perdisk=False)

Return system disk I/O statistics as a namedtuple including the following attributes:
    read_count: number of reads
    write_count: number of writes
    read_bytes: number of bytes read
    write_bytes: number of bytes written
    read_time: time spent reading from disk (in milliseconds)
    write_time: time spent writing to disk (in milliseconds)
```

The code you found confirms that all the memory usage and IO counts are reported in MB (= bytes * 1024 * 1024).

Answer (score 13):

I will just leave this here for future reference.

Reading through

- `snakemake >= 6.0.0` [benchmark module](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/f55801bfabfb916f77fa4ec8f9eb0667e5c8a92e/snakemake/benchmark.py)
- `psutil`'s [memory_info()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.memory_info), [memory_full_info()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.memory_full_info), [io_counters()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.io_counters), [cpu_times()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_times)

as previously suggested:

| colname | type (unit) | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s | float (seconds) | Running time in seconds |
| h:m:s | string (-) | Running time in hour, minutes, seconds format |
| max_rss | float (MB) | Maximum "Resident Set Size”, this is the non-swapped physical memory a process has used. |
| max_vms | float (MB) | Maximum “Virtual Memory Size”, this is the total amount of virtual memory used by the process |
| max_uss | float (MB) | “Unique Set Size”, this is the memory which is unique to a process and which would be freed if the process was terminated right now. |
| max_pss | float (MB) | “Proportional Set Size”, is the amount of memory shared with other processes, accounted in a way that the amount is divided evenly between the processes that share it (Linux only) |
| io_in | float (MB) | the number of MB read (cumulative). |
| io_out | float (MB) | the number of MB written (cumulative). |
| mean_load | float (-) | CPU usage over time, divided by the total running time (first row) |
| cpu_time | float(-) | CPU time summed for user and system |

Comment: Huh, how come I'm having values such as `0.02` in `io_out`? Number of operations should be an int, shouldn't it?

Comment: According to @heathobrien answer, `io_in` and `io_out` correspond to "number of MB read" and "number of MB written", so they are also in `MB`.

Comment: You are correct, I read some stuff too literally from the docs. I edited the original to reflect the correct measurements.